# Can I snap the cursor to a vertex which has an armature modifier applied?

Tags: modifiers, armature, interface, snapping, 3d-cursor

Hitting Shift+S provides several options in a wheel, including snapping the cursor to the selection. This works in both object and edit mode. However, if I'm dealing with a model that has an armature deformation applied to it, the cursor always snaps to the original, undeformed, position; it does not see the post-armature position.

Is it possible at all to snap the cursor to the deformed armature position? I imagine this is true with other deformation modifiers, too; but they just aren't considered by it, by default.

(To some extent I understand this; some cases, like a Mirror modifier or an Array modifier, would be a little vague. However, it's a show-stopper when I'm working on a heavily animated mesh and need to, say, spawn a specific shape in the scene, at a specific place on the mesh, at a specific time. Lots of manual adjustments.)

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, it's like the transform gizmos that don't stick to the selected vertex when it is changed by the Armature modifier, I think it would make sense to change that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have at least two options; neither is ideal.

1. You can simply project the cursor onto the mesh.  Use your cursor tool and click on the mesh, with "Surface Project" on sidebar/tool enabled, which it is by default.  It does not snap to any particular vertex, but just doing it to eye, you can be very, very close.
2. You can use another object constrained in a way to acquire the exact position of a vertex, post-modifiers, and then snap your cursor to the position of that object.  There are a number of ways to do this.  One would be to mark the exact vertex you wanted with membership in a vertex group and then create an empty with a Copy Location constraint targeting that mesh, limited to that vertex group.  Then, you can simply select the empty and snap cursor to selection.  Any number of constraints could do this, although in various ways; vertex parenting in rest pose could even do it.

We could even combine these.  We could have an empty with a shrinkwrap constraint, set to nearest vertex, snap it to the location of a surface-projected cursor, then snap the cursor to its location.  This way, we can get the exact location of any vertex that is a part of a face, even in the case of generative modifiers like array or mirror.  And we can reuse the same empty, just moving it about to snap to whatever vertex we wanted.

For creating stuff carefully around deformed geometry, as a more general solution, a shrinkwrap modifier can be useful.  You can limit the shrinkwrap with a vertex group so it only affects some vertices; you can apply it when you're done modelling; you can set it to nearest face or nearest vertex (or other options) as desired.

Comment: I was worried that this was going to end up being a Right Click Select kind of thing. Thank you for the workarounds. My other option has been to parent it (usually in an awkward place) to the unmodified mesh and make microadjustments to get it to work right post-deformation.

Comment: I'm submitted the idea "Snap To Cursor (Absolute)" on RCS. It would basically snap the cursor to the average of the points selected, presented to the internal logic in the same way that they are to my eyes. There might be a better name for it. It *sounds* easy enough, but I'm not as familiar as I would like to be with Blender's internal C++ and the team has a lot going on right now as it is... so we'll see what happens.